# How to store positional indexes and document id's in a Hashmap<Hashmap<ArrayList>>

Tags: java, text, arraylist, hashmap

I have text files within a directory. What i need to do is;
---for each word in all files
---find positional indexes of each word within a file
---find each file that the word has passed

In order to do this;

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>>
```

I want to use a structure as above.

```
String word;
        String pattern = "[[^\\w\\süÜıİöÖşŞğĞçÇ]\\d]+";
        while ((word = infile.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] wordList = word.replaceAll(pattern, " ").split("\\s+");

            for (int j = 0; j < wordList.length; j++) {
                if(!wordList[j].isEmpty()){
                        if(!refinedDict.containsKey(wordList[j])){
                            refinedDict.put(wordList[j], 1);
                        }
                        else{
                            refinedDict.put(wordList[j], refinedDict.get(wordList[j])+1);
                        }
                    }//end of for
                 }//end if
                else{
                 //do something   
                }
            }//end for
        }//end while

 Set<String> keys=refinedDict.keySet();
 List<String> list=sortList(keys);
 Iterator<String> it=list.iterator();
 while(it.hasNext()){
       String key=it.next();
       outfile.write(key + "\t" + refinedDict.get(key) + "\n");
```

How can i use the ArrayList in HashMap in a HashMap

**EDIT**
After applying toto2's solution implementation works. However, in order to write it to a file as --->
 word[fileId{positions}, fileId{positions}...] 
What can be done? 
Implementing serializable is not useful for such a design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I define two new classes `FileId` and `PositionInFile` instead of `Integer`s for clarity.

```
Map<String, Map<FileId, List<PositionInFile>>> wordsWithLocations;

for (int j = 0; j < wordList.length; j++) {
   if (!wordList[j].isEmpty()){
      if (!wordsWithLocations.containsKey(wordList[j])) {
         Map<FileId, List<PositionInFile>> map = new HashMap<>();
         List<PositionInFile> list = new ArrayList<>();
         list.add(wordPosition[j]);
         map.put(fileId, list);
         wordsWithLocations.put(wordList[j], map);
       } else {
          Map<FileId, List<PositionInFile>> map = 
                          wordsWithLocation.get(wordList[j]);
          if (map.contains(fileId)) {
             map.get(fileId).add(wordPosition[j]);
          } else {
             List<PositionInFile> list = new ArrayList<>();
             list.add(wordPosition[j]);
             map.put(fileId, list);
          }
       }
    }
}

...

for (String word : wordsWithLocation) {
   int nAppearances = 0;
   for (List<PositionInFile> positions :      
                            wordsWithLocation.get(word).values()) {
      nAppearances += positions.size();
   }
   System.out.println(word + " appears " + nAppearances + " times.");
}
```

However I think it would be simpler and cleaner to define:

```
public class WordLocation {
   FileId fileId;
   PositionInFile position;

   ... 
}
```

and then just have a `Map<String, List<WordLocation>>`.  The downside is that you don't have such an explicit mapping to the files.  The information is still there however, and  the `List<WordLocation>` should even have the locations listed in the same order as the files were processed.

Comment: It works! However, i tried really hard to write it into a file and i have failed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your HashMap defined as above and add an entry like this:

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>> outer = ...
HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> inner = ...
inner.put(1, new ArrayList<Integer>());
outer.put("key1", inner);
```

you can retrieve the `ArrayList` as:

```
ArrayList<Integer> arr = outer.get("key1").get(1);
```

Comment: Do you really need the casts?

Comment: @toto2: you're right, with the generic version they are not necessary. I've edited.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly.
But here's a general way that I use for a Map that the value is of Collection type.

```
Map<String, Collection<something>> map ...
for ... do some job
   if map.containsKey(keyFound) {
      map.get(foundKey).add(foundValue);
   } else {
      Collection <- create collection
      Collection.add(foundValue);
      map.put(foundKey, collection)
   }
```

You can also check Google Guava multi-maps.

Hope that helps...

Answer (score 0):

nested Map would work. however I would create a class for that, i.e.

```
class WordsInFile{

String fileName;
Map<String, List<Integer>> wordIdxMap;

}
```

this does actually no big difference with nesting maps. but more readable, and you can add methods like findWord(...)...  to avoid to be get lost by invoking twice of maps' get(object) methods. It let you know what you are about to get.

i don't know if it is a good idea...